# How to change position of woocommerce "added to cart" message

Tags: plugins, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using `woocommerce version 2.3.13` and I want to change position of `woocommerce messages` like "Product was successfully added to cart", which appears on the top of the product page when I click on "add to cart" button.

I want this message to appear somewhere else.

I've tired many solutions including [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128450/reposition-woocommerce-message)  by removing '`woocommerce_show_messages`' on '`woocommerce_before_single_product`' hook

**code**: `remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_show_messages' );`

and then calling `woocommerce_show_messages();` function where I want the message to appear but with no luck.

Anyone please help me in this regard.

**EDIT:**

I've forgot to mention that I am using storefront theme and using custom template for single product.

And these messages are appearing at the top of page by default.

Comment: Hi @CodePoet did you find a solution for this ? (I am using WooCommerce 3+ btw)

Answer (score 2):

The messages 'Product was successfully added to cart' are woocommerce notices.
These messages are printed by the function

```
    <?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
```

Try changing the position of this function in template.

To add notices via hooks

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
```

**STOREFRONT Theme Edit:**
** Works with Woocoommerce: 3.1.2 + Storefront: 2.2.5 **

In storefront theme the `wc_print_notices` is hooked into `storefront_content_top`

so to remove messages from top in storefront theme you need to add following code in `functions.php`

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wc_print_notices', 10 ); /*Archive Product*/
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 ); /*Single Product*/
remove_action( 'storefront_content_top', 'storefront_shop_messages', 1 );
```

and add function

```
wc_print_notices();
```

Wherever you want notices to appear.

EDIT: The messages will not appear on Single Product Page and Archive Product Page. Though they might appear on any other woocommerce page(cart, checkout, etc).

Comment: This is correct. Notices are not added via hook, they are called directly.

Comment: notices can be added via hooks
`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );`

Comment: They sure *can* be, but as you pointed out in there are places where the function is called directly. Actually I was mistaken before, they *are* added to `woocommerce_before_single_product` and `woocommerce_before_shop_loop`. It seems to be mostly shortcodes and ajax callbacks that call the function directly.

Comment: @Akash K. Actually I want the message to appear somewhere in the middle of product page, currently it is appearing at the top of page (even before breadcrumbs). Please note that I am using storefront theme and custom template for single product.

Comment: The `wc_print_notices` action is actually hooked in `'woocommerce_before_single_product`... Unhook the function from this action using `remove_action` and whereever in your template you want the notice to appear just call `wc_print_notices()` in the template itself.

Comment: if you're not calling `do_action('woocommerce_before_single_product');` in your template just call the function `wc_print_notices()` in the template.

Comment: @AkashK. 
I've tried `remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices')`

and 

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wc_print_notices')` but still somehow the notices are appearing on the top of product page.

Comment: @AngryCoder did you check the updated answer for storefront theme?

Comment: none of the 3 solutions work for Storefront (top of the product page)... any valid solution someone ?

Comment: @Louis did you even try the above solutions? I just finished testing it on storefront because someone downvoted my answer. It's working fine.

Comment: Hi @AkashK. yes I tested with Storefront 2.2.5, it doesn't work for me, I added: `remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wc_print_notices', 10 ); /*Archive Product*/
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 ); /*Single Product*/
remove_action( 'storefront_content_top', 'storefront_shop_messages', 1 );` and as you can see the notices are still at the same position : http://hemen.makemy.biz/product/boxer-albar-blanc-hodei/

Comment: well, it was tested with Storefront and your theme is totally customized. Why would you expect this to work on your theme?

Comment: I found the code that works for me : `add_action( 'init', 'reposition_sf_messages' );
function reposition_sf_messages(){
    remove_action( 'storefront_content_top','storefront_shop_messages',15 );
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 ); /*Single Product*/
 

 add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'storefront_shop_messages', 1 );

 
}`

Comment: I've posted similar code as my answer. Just my answer was limited to 'Remove Shop Messages'. Plus your theme is customized and the code was not meant for every theme which uses storefront as base theme. Still the code to remove the messages is same as in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (WooCommerce 3.2+) (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46604928/2217647) for @LoicTheAztec)

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'reposition_sf_messages' );
function reposition_sf_messages(){
    if( is_product() ) {
        remove_action( 'storefront_content_top','storefront_shop_messages',15 );
    }
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 ); /*Single Product*/
    add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'storefront_shop_messages', 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for a solution here it goes.

you can use something like
`remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );`

Now put this code where you want to show the notices.
`<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have woocommerce 6.3.1 installed and nothing worked for me. In the end I started looking at the woocommerce files and found that it is "woocommerce_output_all_notices".
So I went to my functions.php of my child theme and put the following:

```
//Remove for original position
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );

//Move under cart button (option 1)
add_action ( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 35 ); 

//Move under cart button (option 2)
add_action ( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'mover_mensaje_product_added', 35 );
function mover_mensaje_product_added() {
    echo woocommerce_show_messages();
}

//Change text (optional)
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'custom_add_to_cart_message' );
function custom_add_to_cart_message() {
   $message = '¡Estupendo! Ya tienes el producto en tu carrito :)' ;
   return $message;
}
```

From option 1 and option 2, you should only choose 1. Or you put one or the other. I only give you alternatives that have worked for me, and in my case both options are valid.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_show_messages' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'woocommerce_show_messages', 15 );
```

Here `third parameter` is for `positioning priority`

Comment: yes I already tired this but it is not working in my case. Please see my edit that may clear the situation and you can easily point out a solution.

Comment: I hope this [link](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/add_action/) will have some guideline, it states fourth parameter, and the third on is categorized as `priority`!

Answer (score -1):

i think this will help you ............

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_my_page', 'wc_print_notices', 10);
```

Now go to your page, where you want the messages displayed, and add

```
<?php
      do_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_page' );
?>
```

Comment: thanks for replying...

but this is not working. Please see my edit that may clear the situation.

Answer (score -1):

This is the complete code to add in functions.php of the theme.

```
function move_woocommerce_message(){
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
  add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_print_notices', 35 );  
}
add_filter('wp', 'move_woocommerce_message');
```