# Change the position of of WooCommerce notices in storefront theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, notice, storefront

I am trying to change the position of storefront_shop_messages in my Storefront (WooCommerce) child theme. So I have added this code in the functions.php of my active theme:

```
remove_action( 'storefront_content_top', 'storefront_shop_messages', 15 );
add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'storefront_shop_messages', 1 );
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, is there a more generic hook you can think of ? And particularly can you advise on how to move those messages only on single product page ?

Comment: So what's the best approach to move the warning message in storefront below the ADD TO CART button in the product page ?

Comment: Sorry @LoicTheAztec I got mixed up in the questions/answers ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to get what you are expecting in your comments (meaning displaying WooCommerce notices after add to cart button on product single page only):

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'customize_notices' );
function customize_notices(){
    if( is_product() )
        remove_action( 'storefront_content_top', 'storefront_shop_messages', 15 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 34 );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works on storefront theme with WooCommerce 3.1+

Comment: I get a strange php error though with this code : Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'woocommerce_before_main_content' not found or invalid function name in /home/hugomatha/hemen.makemy.biz/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298`

Comment: So I used instead of  `add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 34 );`  I used this line : `add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'storefront_shop_messages', 1 );`