# Woocommerce -- How do I edit the position of notices on my account page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, notice

My problem is when I click Save Address, the success message ruins everything. I want to edit the position of the success message. How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where to place the success message?
also, refer this link[ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565865/change-the-position-of-of-woocommerce-notices-in-storefront-theme]

Comment: Please refer to this link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565865/change-the-position-of-of-woocommerce-notices-in-storefront-theme>