# Move woocommerce notices for checkout page to "before_cart"

Tags: woocommerce

I have modified my checkout page to show the cart first and then the rest of checkout page. I used this code snippet:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'bbloomer_cart_on_checkout_page_only', 5 );
function bbloomer_cart_on_checkout_page_only() {
if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) return; 
echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_cart]');
}
```

But now the woocommerce notices are showing up under the cart.

I know I can use the `remove_action()` and `add_action()` for this but how do I find which hook is currently being used and which exact command I need?

I tried this but it doesn't change anything on my checkout page:

```
function move_checkout_woo_notices() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'wc_print_notices', 10 ); 
    add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'wc_print_notices', 1 );
}
add_action ( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'move_checkout_woo_notices' );
```

Preferably, I would post the notices directly under the page title.
(my page layout is always header > page title > content so using page title as the relative position seems to be the safest.) Is there a hook for that?

I checked this [Change the position of of WooCommerce notices in storefront theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565865/change-the-position-of-of-woocommerce-notices-in-storefront-theme/46604928#46604928) but the code given is theme specific and I use another theme (Astra).

Comment: _"I have modified my checkout page to show the cart first and then the rest of checkout page."_. Given the lack of information on how you did that, it's difficult to give an appropriate answer to your question. 
If you replace all add_actions with remove_action as can be found on the following [link](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/includes/wc-template-hooks.php#L307-L309) 
and then test them 1 by 1 you will automatically find out which remove_action is the right one. 
Based on that you can come to an answer to your question

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r, I edited my question to show the code I used to add the cart page to my checkout page. You basically answered my question by giving the list of possible hooks. I tried the remove_action() with the 3 possible hooks but none of them remove the notices in my checkout page. Could there be something else wrong?

Comment: @businessbloomer is the author of the above snippet, he might be able to help you